# React navigate router v6 invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Im trying to redirect my user when the user is logged in. but all my methods i found so far wont work. etg im trying to use useNavigate function using react router v6.

but for some reason i get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

at:

```
/login.jsx:35
let navigate = useNavigate();
```

function:

```
PerformLogin = () => {
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  const username = this.state.username;
  const password = this.state.password;
  if (username === '') {
    console.log("please enter username");
  } else if (password === '') {
    console.log("please enter password");
  } else {
    console.log("username of login: ",this.state.username);
    axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_DATAURL + `/login`,{ username: username, password: password },{withCredentials: true})
    .then(res => {
      res = res.data;
      console.log(res);
      console.log(res.data);
      if (res.type) {
        console.log("navigating logged in");
        navigate.push('/crime');
        //return <Navigate to="/crime" />;
      }
    })
  }
}
```

**Q: what do i have to do to fix this and be able to redirect my user?**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### Edit: For react-router v6

In react-router v6 there is no `withRouter` nor `useHistory`. I would recommend to refactor your component to use hooks for the sake of simplicity, but an alternative solution is to create a wrapper component that will pass the navigate function obtained from the hook as a prop:

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  //...
    PerformLogin = () => {
        const username = this.state.username;
        const password = this.state.password;
        // ...
        this.props.navigate('/crime');
    }
}

function WithNavigate(props) {
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    return <MyComponent {...props} navigate={navigate} />
}

export default WithNavigate
```

---

`useHistory` is a hook and hooks can only be used inside "function" components.

However I can guess you are using it from a "class" component, since there are some `this.state`, so you cannot use the hook there.

Another approach that should work for you would be to wrap your component inside a [`withRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/native/api/withRouter):

```js
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  //...
    PerformLogin = () => {
        const history = this.props.history;
        const username = this.state.username;
        const password = this.state.password;
        // ...
    }
}

export default withRouter(MyComponent)
```

The withRouter will inject the history as a prop.

Comment: There is no useHistory hook in 6.0. what to do in V6? would withrouter work in v6 too?

Comment: Edited to add instructions for react v6

Comment: thank you . how would you do this with hooks? @anthony

Comment: It would still be `useNavigate` but also to split the class in smaller functional components. `PerformLogin` would become its own functional component and would use `useState` rather than `this.state`. The fetching logic would be in a `useEffect` hook etc. One benefit of that approach would be that the `useNavigate` could be placed closer to where it is used, rather than injected at the top-level.

Answer (score 1):

In react-router-dom latest **version(v6)** you cannot use `this.props.match.params.id` and `this.props.history` (in react latest vesion `history` replace with `navigate`). Besides you cannot call them in class component. To call them in class component make a function first -

```
    import { useParams, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

    export function withParamsAndNavigate(Component) {
      return (props) => (
       <Component {...props} params={useParams()} navigate={useNavigate()} />
  );
}
```

- I want to use it for `ProductDetails` component. That's given below -

  ```
   import { withParamsAndNavigate } from "./getParamsAndNavigate.js";

   class ProductDetails extends React.Component {
    state = {//}

  render() {
   const{params,navigate} = this.props;
    // params.id - will return the id,
    // navigate('yourUrl') - will redirect the target url.
    return (
       //
     );
    }
   }

  export default withParamsAndNavigate(ProductDetails);
  ```
- Here is my `App` module where I defined my routes -

  ```
       import React from "react";
       import { Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";
       import Product from "./components/Product";
       import ProductDetails "./components/ProductDetails";

       function App() {
         return (
             <div>
                <main role='main' className='container'>
                  <Routes>
                     <Route path='/product' element={<Product />} />
                     <Route path="/product/:id"} element={<ProductDetails />} />
                  </Routes>
                </main>
            </div>
         );
        }
       export default App;
  ```
- It works for me and hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can only call hooks at the top level (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) inside a component.

Therefore, this is invalid, being it's not only in an if statement, in a promise's `.then` function, and also does not appear to even be a functional component, rather, just a function:

```
if (res.type) {
        console.log("navigating logged in");
        navigate.push('/crime');
        //return <Navigate to="/crime" />;
    }
```

I would instead attempt doing something like setting a flag, and then navigating based upon that flag:

```
  PerformLogin = () => {
        let navigate = useNavigate();
        let shouldNavigate = false;
        const username = this.state.username;
        const password = this.state.password;
        if (username === '') {
            console.log("please enter username");
        } else if (password === '') {
            console.log("please enter password");
        } else {
                  console.log("username of login: ",this.state.username);
                   axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_DATAURL + `/login`,{ username: username, password: password },{withCredentials: true})
      .then(res => {
          res = res.data;
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
        if (res.type) {
            console.log("navigating logged in");
            shouldNavigate = true;
            //return <Navigate to="/crime" />;
        }
        
        
      })
              
  
        }
        
        navigate.push(shouldNavigate ? '/crime' : currentURL);
  }
```

But I would avoid this altogether and simply utilize the useHistory hook to get an instance of history and work on that (I haven't tested this either but it should work):

```
  PerformLogin = () => {
        const history = useHistory();
        const username = this.state.username;
        const password = this.state.password;
        if (username === '') {
            console.log("please enter username");
        } else if (password === '') {
            console.log("please enter password");
        } else {
                  console.log("username of login: ",this.state.username);
                   axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_DATAURL + `/login`,{ username: username, password: password },{withCredentials: true})
      .then(res => {
          res = res.data;
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
        if (res.type) {
            console.log("navigating logged in");
            history.push('/crime');
            //return <Navigate to="/crime" />;
        }
        
        
      })
              
  
        }
        
        
  }
```

**Note: You have to do this directly in your component itself, you can't use hooks in a normal function that isn't a component.**

Comment: There is no useHistory hook in 6.0. what to do in V6?

Answer (score 0):

```
*An example of how you can use.useHsitory has not been working properly in v6

import React from 'react';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';


const StatusCodeCat: React.FC = () => {
//   const history = useHistory();
  const history = createBrowserHistory();
  console.log(history);
  


  return (
    <div>
        never
    </div>
  );
}

export default StatusCodeCat;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `window.location.assign(routeAddresses.dashboard);`

Answer (score -1):

you don't use `useNavigate()` in ordinary function

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, please prefer code than image : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question