# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to navigate to a new page when clicking on a button. I used history but it not working. Using React-router-dom v6.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom'
import ListEmployeeComponent from './components/ListEmployeeComponent';
import HeaderComponent from './components/HeaderComponent';
import FooterComponent from './components/FooterComponent';
import CreateEmployeeComponent from './components/CreateEmployeeComponent';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
        <Router>
              <HeaderComponent />
                <div className="container">
                    <Routes> 
                          <Route path = "/" index element = {<ListEmployeeComponent/>}></Route>
                          <Route path = "/employees" element = {<ListEmployeeComponent/>}></Route>
                          <Route path = "/add-employee" element = {<CreateEmployeeComponent/>}></Route>
                    </Routes>
                </div>
              <FooterComponent />
        </Router>
        
    </div>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

**ListEmployeeComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import EmployeeService from '../services/EmployeeService';

// import { createHashHistory } from 'history'
// export const history = createHashHistory()
class ListEmployeeComponent extends Component {
    
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            employees: []
        }
        this.addEmployee = this.addEmployee.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        EmployeeService.getEmployees().then((res) => {
            this.setState({ employees: res.data});
        });
    }
    addEmployee(){
         this.props.history.push('/add-employee');
    }
    
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
           <h2 className="text-center">Employees List</h2>
           <div className = "row">
                    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.addEmployee}> Add Employee</button>
            </div>
                 <br></br>
            <table className='table table-striped table-bordered'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Employee First Name</th>
                        <th>Employee Last Name</th>
                        <th>Employee Email Id</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    {
                        this.state.employees.map(
                            employee => 
                            <tr key ={employee.id}>
                                <td>{employee.firstName}</td>
                                <td>{employee.lastName}</td>
                                <td>{employee.emailId}</td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default ListEmployeeComponent
```

**CreateEmployeeComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
// import EmployeeService from '../services/EmployeeService';
// import { createHashHistory } from 'history'
// export const history = createHashHistory()

class CreateEmployeeComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            // id: this.props.match.params.id,
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            emailId: ''
        }
        this.changeFirstNameHandler = this.changeFirstNameHandler.bind(this);
        this.changeLastNameHandler = this.changeLastNameHandler.bind(this);
        this.saveOrUpdateEmployee = this.saveOrUpdateEmployee.bind(this);
        
    }

    saveOrUpdateEmployee = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let employee = {firstName: this.state.firstName, lastName: this.state.lastName, emailId: this.state.emailId};
        console.log('employee => ' + JSON.stringify(employee));
    }


    changeFirstNameHandler= (event) => {
        this.setState({firstName: event.target.value});
    }

    changeLastNameHandler= (event) => {
        this.setState({lastName: event.target.value});
    }

    changeEmailHandler= (event) => {
        this.setState({emailId: event.target.value});
    }

    cancel(){
        this.props.history.push('/employees');
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               <div className='container'>
                   <div className='row'>
                       <div className='card col-md-6 offset-md-3 offset-md-3'>
                        <h3 className='text-center'>Add Employee</h3>
                        <div className='card-body'>
                            <form>
                                <div className='form-group'>
                                <label> First Name: </label>
                                            <input placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" className="form-control" 
                                                value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.changeFirstNameHandler}/>
                                </div>
                                <div className = "form-group">
                                            <label> Last Name: </label>
                                            <input placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" className="form-control" 
                                                value={this.state.lastName} onChange={this.changeLastNameHandler}/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className = "form-group">
                                            <label> Email Id: </label>
                                            <input placeholder="Email Address" name="emailId" className="form-control" 
                                                value={this.state.emailId} onChange={this.changeEmailHandler}/>
                                        </div>
                                        <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.saveOrUpdateEmployee}>Save</button>
                                        <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.cancel.bind(this)} style={{marginLeft: "10px"}}>Cancel</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                       </div>

                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CreateEmployeeComponent
```

How to resolve this Type Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') in React Js. Please rectify. WithRouter is all not working. Hash history also not working. I am using react-router-dom v6.
Please rectify how to clear this in class component.Navigate router is not working

Comment: General rule of thumb with these types of errors is either it's not set up correctly or you're not accounting for default values; if undefined or null is the default value, you have to wrap function calls in conditionals checking to see if the variable/object is set before use.

Answer (score 2):

In react-router v6, you have to use "navigate" function.
Check this [:https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#navigation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#navigation)

Comment: Where to change? , can you edit the code

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63786452/react-navigate-router-v6-invalid-hook-call